# Check for equality between two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I check for equality between the elements of two arrays without using external libraries (and preferably using ES5)?

I want to check for equality between them without caring about the order of the elements. So the two arrays `[1,2,3]` and `[2,3,1]` are equal in my situation.

I guess I should write a function

```
function isEqual(arr1, arr2) {
  arr1.forEach(el => {
    if (arr2.indexOf(el) === -1) {
      return false;
    }
  });

  arr2.forEach(el => {
    if (arr1.indexOf(el) === -1) {
      return false;
    }
  });

  return true;
}
```

Comment: There are tons of questions here such as what if they are in different length and have duplicate items.

Comment: Is `[1,2,3]` and `[1,3,3,2]` also equal for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** and **[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** methods. Sort both the arrays ang compare them after converting to JSON string.

```js
function isEqual(arr1, arr2) {
  return JSON.stringify(arr1.sort()) === JSON.stringify(arr2.sort());
}

console.log(isEqual([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1]));
console.log(isEqual([1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 1]));
console.log(isEqual([1, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 1]));
console.log(isEqual([1, 2, 3, 3], [2, 4, 1, 1]));
```

---

Or instead of **[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** you can also use **[`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** method( Suggested by ***@JonCarter*** ) which makes it little more simple.

```js
function isEqual(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.sort().join() === arr2.sort().join();
}

console.log(isEqual([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1]));
console.log(isEqual([1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 1]));
console.log(isEqual([1, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 1]));
console.log(isEqual([1, 2, 3, 3], [2, 4, 1, 1]));
```

Comment: I like this -- it's short and elegant.  Just a suggestion: using Array.join() might be a little better than JSON.stringify.  e.g. `arr1.sort().join() === arr2.sort().join()`

Comment: @JonCarter :  wow that would be much better ..... thanks and updated the answer with your suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks! Great solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to assert the values are equal. This is very rudimentary though as uses a strict equality check which has its limitations. But this shows the rough framework for a iterating over the array.

NOTE: Since arrays are index based lists it is assumed that for them to be equal they would need to have equal values at the same index.

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
var arr2 = [1,2,3,4];
var arr3 = [1,2,4];
var arr4 = [1,2,2,4];

function isArrEql(a1, a2) {
  return a1.length === a2.length && a1.every(function(v, i) {
    return v === a2[i];
  });
}

console.log('arr1, arr2: ', isArrEql(arr1, arr2));
console.log('arr1, arr2: ', isArrEql(arr1, arr3));
console.log('arr1, arr2: ', isArrEql(arr1, arr4));
```

Comment: But is `a1.every((v, i) => v === a2[i])` the same as `a2.every((v, i) => v === a1[i])`? Don't I have to check both ways?

Comment: @Jamgreen That is what the length check is for. If both arrays are the same length then iterating over one and matching the corresponding value from the other array would have the same result.